# How to reuse an existing python Enum in Django for choices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, enums

Django has its own [Enumeration types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) like `model.TextChoices`.

However, if you already use traditional python `Enum` objects in your codebase, it would be nice to reuse them for fields definition without redefining all the values.

Is there an elegant straightforward way to do this without too much boilerplate?

What I tried:

- building a `models.TextChoices` class from the `Enum` seems impossible without manually declaring the values
- building the `choices` parameter from the `Enum` instead of dealing with `models.TextChoices` but then things like `obj.field == ENUM.XXX` won't work because Enums don't do value comparisons like `models.TextChoices` does among other things.

Any elegant way to do this?

```py
form enum import Enum

class YEAR_IN_SCHOOL(Enum):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    GRADUATE = 'GR'

class MyModel(models.Model):
    year_in_school = django_model_field_choices_using_enum(YEAR_IN_SCHOOL)
```

So that:

- Comparaison with the ENUM works

```py
my_model.year_in_school == YEAR_IN_SCHOOL.FRESHMAN
```

- Saving using the Enum works

```py
my_model.year_in_school = YEAR_IN_SCHOOL.FRESHMAN
my_model.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as regular django `models.CharField` with `choices` from your `Enum`

I.e:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2, 
        choices=[(x.value, x.name) for x in YEAR_IN_SCHOOL]
    )
```

However, usage in this case will be a bit different (you need to specify `.value` on comparison/saving:

```
my_model.year_in_school == YEAR_IN_SCHOOL.FRESHMAN.value
```

If you want to have it without `.value` - then remove `Enum` - i.e. make a plain class.

Then retrieving choices will be with `inspect`:

```
import inspect

class YEAR_IN_SCHOOL:
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    GRADUATE = 'GR'

choices = [(y, x) for x, y in inspect.getmembers(YEAR_IN_SCHOOL)]
```

And assign/comparison will be the same as in your question

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite old question, but I had a similar one and did not find an answer anywhere, so, here is mine.

You said:

> building a models.TextChoices class from the Enum seems impossible without manually declaring the values

In fact, this is possible (but not really elegant). As `models.TextChoices` extends `enum.Enum`, you can use the [functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#functional-api) to dynamically build a `TextChoices`:

```py
from enum import Enum
from django.db import models

class YEAR_IN_SCHOOL(Enum):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    GRADUATE = 'GR'

# Create a model.TextChoices dynamically from the Enum
choices = [(e.name, e.value) for e in YEAR_IN_SCHOOL]
MY_YEAR_IN_SCHOOL = models.TextChoices('MY_YEAR_IN_SCHOOL', choices)

print(MY_YEAR_IN_SCHOOL.choices)  # ==> [('FR', 'Freshman'), ('SO', 'Sophomore'), ('JR', 'Junior'), ('SR', 'Senior'), ('GR', 'Graduate')]
print(MY_YEAR_IN_SCHOOL.FRESHMAN)  # ==> FR

# Now use a regular CharField with choices attr in your model    
class MyModel(models.Model):
    year_in_school = models.CharField(, choices=MY_YEAR_IN_SCHOOL.choices, default=MY_YEAR_IN_SCHOOL.FRESHMAN)
```